# Java - Security - Retrieve CRL data from a Certificate

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, certificate-revocation

**Goal**: Retrieve the Certificate Revocation List information for a given Certificate.

**Reason**: When a `java.security.cert.PKIXParameters` object is set to enable checking of certificate revocation status via `PKIXParameters#setRevocationEnabled(true);` it uses an instance of `sun.security.provider.certpath.CrlRevocationChecker`
 This checker requires a call to `PKIXParameters#addCertStore(...)` which adds a `java.security.cert.CertStore` containing an implementation of `X509CRL` which holds the CRL information the validator can check against.

**Question**: Does there exist a library or implementation for retrieving this data ? or does it have to be done manually? (example of manual below). A library would most likely support all possible types of connections/exception/errors that could arise, while the manual solution needs to work to bring up to enterprise standards.

The certificate can be in any of these x509 certificate wrappers

```
java.security.cert.X509Certificate
org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder
org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject
```

Java Code for retrieving CRL data manually

```
static List<X509CRLObject> getCRLSFromCertPath(CertPath certPath, CertificateFactory certificateFactory) {
        List<X509CRLObject> x509CRLs = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<? extends Certificate> certificates = certPath.getCertificates();
        for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
            try {
                X509CertImpl x509Cert = new X509CertImpl(certificate.getEncoded());
                CRLDistributionPointsExtension crlDistroExten = x509Cert.getCRLDistributionPointsExtension();
                if (crlDistroExten != null) {
                    ArrayList<DistributionPoint> distros = (ArrayList<DistributionPoint>) crlDistroExten.get(CRLDistributionPointsExtension.POINTS);
                    for (DistributionPoint distributionPoint : distros) {
                        GeneralNames distroName = distributionPoint.getFullName();
                        for (int i = 0; i < distroName.size(); ++i) {
                            URI uri = ((URIName) distroName.get(i).getName()).getURI();
                            InputStream inputStream = new URL(uri.toString()).openConnection().getInputStream();
                            X509CRLObject x509CRL = (X509CRLObject) certificateFactory.generateCRL(inputStream);
                            x509CRLs.add(x509CRL);
                            inputStream.close(); // Move this somewhere better
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (CertificateException | IOException | CRLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return x509CRLs;
    }
```